# Difference between != and not ( = )

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

What is the difference between the `not()` operator and `!=`?

See this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <test>123</test>
</body>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:if test = "/body/test = (123, 2)">true1</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test = "not(/body/test != (123, 2))">true2</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMx

Why do i get `true1` as a result, but not `true2`? I would expect the two lines to be equivalent. Why are they not?

Comment: Shouldn't your second test be: `"not(/body/test = (123, 2))"`? Its; still not the same thing as the first one, but at least it makes sense to ask what's the difference.

Comment: No, it is meant to be like this. I wonder why the two `if`s are not equivalent. Why is this not a "double negative" and therefore the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question/s you didn't ask, but should have:

```
"123 = (123, 2)"
```

returns true because 123 is equal to 123.

```
"not(123 = (123, 2))"
```

returns false because as shown above, the inner expression is true - and the outer not() merely reverses it.

```
"123 != (123, 2)"
```

returns true, because 123 is not-equal to 2.

```
"not(123 != (123, 2))"
```

returns false because as shown above, the inner expression is true, and the outer not() merely reverses it.

For reference, see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-value-comparisons

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The surprising fact for me was that `=` and `!=` are not mutually exclusive, which I intuitively thought at first.

Comment: I have just now added a reference to the standard. The operative sentence can be found in section 3.5.2: "*The result of the comparison is true if and only if there is a pair of atomic values, one in the first operand sequence and the other in the second operand sequence, that have the required magnitude relationship.*"

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to realise with the "general" comparison operators in XPath (including `=` and `!=`) is that they are implicitly existentially quantified over their argument sequences. The expression `X = Y` means the same as the *explicitly* [quantified expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions)

```
some $x in X, $y in Y satisfies $x eq $y
```

(`eq` being the single item equality operator).  So `not(X = Y)` means

```
not(some $x in X, $y in Y satisfies $x eq $y)
```

which is equivalent to saying

```
every $x in X, $y in Y satisfies $x ne $y
```

Conversely `X != Y` means

```
some $x in X, $y in Y satisfies $x ne $y
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth noting the difference between how XPath handles this and how SQL handles it. SQL uses three-valued logic and NULL values, so the effect is that if AUTHOR is absent (null) then `AUTHOR="Kay"` and `AUTHOR!="Kay"` both produce "null" (or "undefined", I think they call it), which means that when either expression is used as a predicate in a WHERE clause, the relevant row is not selected. XPath also produces the result that if AUTHOR is absent, neither of the predicates `AUTHOR="Kay"` and `AUTHOR!="Kay"` cause the item to be selected; but unlike SQL, there is no three-valued logic, and this is achieved by having both predicates return false. But the consequence of the predicate returning false is that its inverse `(not(P))` returns true, which leads to the surprising result that `not(AUTHOR="Kay")` has a different effect from `AUTHOR!="Kay"`.

Comment: Good to see that this "surprise" can not only occur when comparing sets with more than one element, but also singletons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are testing against a sequence of items, but the reason

```
/body/test != (123,2)
```

returns `true` is that there is indeed one element in this sequence which is not equal to the value inside `test`, namely "123". This kind of condition returns true, even if not all items in a sequence pass the test.

If you remove `,2` from this sequence:

```
/body/test != (123)
```

this will no longer return true, and its inverse

```
not(/body/test != (123)
```

will return true.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test = "/body/test = (123,2,3,4)">true1</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test = "not(/body/test != (123))">true2</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

```
true1true2
```

Comment: "I have no idea why you are testing against a sequence of items" This is just a simplified example of a problem that I faced. michael.hor257k has already provided a very nice answer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @WilliFischer Yes, Michael has already given a good answer, but in my opinion, he did not explicitly mention that an expression returns true, even if not all items in a sequence would return true on their own.